# how to get (number of) clustered features before map completely rendered?

Tags: openlayers, features, clustering

When you add features into `ol.source.Cluster`, you can access original `ol.Feature` object but clustered `ol.Feature` which is currently displayed on the map.

check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOEvzG) with console log. it doesn't return clustered features.
I guess calculation of cluster is kind of math so there's a way to get the number of clustered feature at least but couldn't find a way without using event such as `postrender` or `postcompose`.